# Recycle (Restart) IIS 7 application pool from within ISAPI extension

Tags: iis, application-pool, isapi

I am developing an ISAPI extension. How to make ISAPI extension to recycle (restart) application pool it is running on?

To achive this I can disable Rapid-Fail Protection and call something like `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);`
But this leads to potential data loss.

Also I can do it by executing external program `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool /apppool.name:"name of my app pool"` But this way I have to configure app pool name somewhere and pool identity has to have administrator privileges.
Also this could be done through WMI, but administrator privileges is needed for this too.
I don't want to give my application pool administrator rights.

So is there a way to give user privilege only to restart application pool but not full administrator rights? May be some setting in Local Security Policy?

Or the only solution is to create a daemon (service) that will run as administrator and wait for message from my ISAPI extension to restart it?